# Sum range with sumif for criteria from InputBox

Tags: excel, vba

i would like to sum a range of rows in a column, for an criteria input value from an InputBox for values that are equal or less than the input value. it's trivial in excel spreadsheets with e.g. =SUMIF(A2:A20;"<=200";C2:C20). i defined something similar in vba, but the return value is 0, i presume that the SUMIF function in vba doesn't recognize the value from InputBox as an integer but as a string. i'm searching for an easy solution to this if possible, below is the syntax i define in vba.

````
Dim A, B, AB As Variant
Dim criteriaRng As Range
Dim sumRng As Range


A = Application.InputBox("Enter the amount of A per year", "A", "A/year", Type:=1)
Worksheets("Sheet").Range("M12").Value = A
B = Application.InputBox("Enter the amount of years B", "B", "Years", Type:=1)
Worksheets("Sheet").Range("N12").Value = B
AB = Worksheets("Sheet").Cells(12, 13) * Worksheets("Sheet").Cells(12, 14)
Worksheets("Sheet").Range("O12").Value = AB

Set criteriaRng = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A20")
Set sumRng = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2:C20")

Worksheets("Sheet").Range("P12").Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(criteriaRng, "<= AB", sumRng)

End Sub```
````

Comment: Try `WorksheetFunction.SumIf(criteriaRng, "<= " & AB, sumRng)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have currently used your variable *within* a string so VBA doesn't recognize the variable. Ditch, `AB` variable alltogether and instead use:

```
Worksheets("Sheet").Range("O12").Value = A*B
```

&

```
Worksheets("Sheet").Range("P12").Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(criteriaRng, "<=" & A*B, sumRng)
```

---

*Sidenote:* `Dim A, B, AB As Variant` will have all three variables dimmed as `Variant`. However, you are returning `Type:=1` data (numeric) so change to `Double` or `Long`. Also the construct you currently use should be `Dim A as Long, B as Long, AB As Long`, to prevent the first two to become `Variant` again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the answer above works without a problem, what's the difference between your and FunThomas' solution if you know - syntax wise.

Comment: Main difference is the use of another variable > `AB`. Both options are perfectly fine. I just opted to scratch that variable since you only use it twice @mauss. Glad it works for you.